# Android Lollipop Sections Separator/Divider

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to create form with 'section separators/dividers' like in Android's Settings activity.

[image]

I inspected the activity by dumping view hierarchy and I noticed that the separator is just some kind of padding with painted gradient. There are just 2 LinearLayouts (1,2) and there is no View between them (3).

[image]

**Is there an "Android" way to paint the same separator?**

I don't want to create ad-hoc solutions.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to know. As I see there are two LinearLayout's with padding between them. This padding makes a separator. Is that an answer to your question?

Comment: If the padding makes a separator then the question is how to make padding look like in screenshot - padding painted with Lollipop standard gradient.

Comment: Lollipop comes with elevation value which makes shadow, see https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html. If you are making app for pre-lollipop you can add there new View with gradient background

Comment: Elevation value is the solution. You saved my day, thanks!

Comment: Could you please make my answer as correct?

Comment: Did you end up creating your own layout then, or could you use the standard PreferencesActivity. If the latter, to what do you add the elevation? My initial guess would be a custom PreferenceCategory layout, but that only contains the preference category title TextView and not the ViewGroup in which the Preference Items lie. Thank you

Comment: Trying to achieve the same.  Do you have a final solution?  If so it would be nice to see you styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lollipop comes with elevation value which makes shadow, see https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html. If you are making app for pre-lollipop you can add there new View with gradient background