# How to get Android system preferences look?

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-preferences

The android system preferences screen on lollipop appears to be using a layout that resembles the "card layout".

[image]

I'm trying to get the same look for my app, but can't see how they achieved it with the default `PreferenceFragment`. Can anyone explain to me, how I can achieve the same effect without having to write my own preferences?

---

Note that I have seen and read these questions, but they don't provide a suitable answer:

- [How to achieve preference category cards like Android System Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372517/how-to-achieve-preference-category-cards-like-android-system-settings) (Answer simply shows how to create a layout that looks similar. Has nothing to do with `PreferenceFragment`)
- [Android Lollipop Sections Separator/Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318222/android-lollipop-sections-separator-divider) (Refers to preferences screenshot, but OP doesn't seem to want to apply it to `PreferenceFragment`)

---

If it's of interest, my current preferences xml looks like this:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_title_general">
        <Preference
            android:key="Prefs.Delete.Row.Token"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_delete_row_token_summary"
            android:title="@string/preferences_delete_row_token_title"/>
        <Preference
            android:key="Prefs.Delete.Cell.Token"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_delete_cell_token_summary"
            android:title="@string/preferences_delete_cell_token_title"/>
        <Preference
            android:key="Prefs.Null.Token"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_null_token_summary"
            android:title="@string/preferences_null_token_title"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_title_appearance">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:dialogTitle="@string/preferences_theme_title"
            android:key="Prefs.Appearance.Theme"
            android:summaryOff="@string/preferences_theme_summary_off"
            android:summaryOn="@string/preferences_theme_summary_on"
            android:switchTextOff="@string/general_no"
            android:switchTextOn="@string/general_yes"
            android:title="@string/preferences_theme_title"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_title_misc">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:dialogTitle="@string/preferences_read_back_title"
            android:key="Prefs.Voice.Feedback"
            android:switchTextOff="@string/general_no"
            android:switchTextOn="@string/general_yes"
            android:title="@string/preferences_read_back_title"/>
        <Preference
            android:key="Prefs.Export.Barcode.Properties"
            android:title="@string/preferences_export_title"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_export_summary"/>
        <Preference
            android:key="Prefs.Show.Eula"
            android:title="@string/preferences_eula_title"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_eula_summary"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And I extend `PreferenceFragment` and load the xml via

```java
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

Comment: Don't have any api >20 device at hand, did you try looking at it with your device monitor -> Dump view hierarchy?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Doing that gives me a hierarchy of layouts. Now what do I do with that? As I said, I'm not looking to reproduce the layout structure in a normal layout, but I rather want to make my existing `PreferenceFragment` look the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've "solved" this by adding a dummy `Preference` between the `PreferenceCategory` items that uses a layout which mimmicks the look in the screenshot in the question:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory></PreferenceCategory>

    <Preference layout="@layout/preference_divider" />

    <PreferenceCategory></PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

With a layout that looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <View     android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="5dp"
              android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom" />

    <View     android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="5dp"
              android:background="@drawable/shadow_top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How have you defined shadow_top and shadow_bottom?

Comment: @JavierDelgado They are just images ([9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)).

Comment: Any chance you share those?

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work to set a background via a custom layout. Also the height didn't apply.

That worked for me though:

```
public class PreferenceDivider  extends Preference {
    public PreferenceDivider(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public PreferenceDivider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources res=getContext().getResources();
        View v=super.onCreateView(parent);
        v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.divider_height)));
        v.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.preference_category_divider, null));
        return v;
    }
}
```

---

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory/>>

    <your.package.path.PreferenceDivider/>

    <PreferenceCategory/>>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

9 patch images are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M5uXXnFc0HHx2BOHQqLtvAXFet4ICDj0/view?usp=sharing